# How to check if interface specifies method using reflection

Tags: reflection, go

I want to reflect to determine whether or not a Go interface contains certain method signatures. I've dynamically got the names and signatures, previously through `reflect`ion on a struct. Here's a simplified example:

```
package main

import "reflect"

func main() {
    type Mover interface {
        TurnLeft() bool
        // TurnRight is missing.
    }

    // How would I check whether TurnRight() bool is specified in Mover?
    reflect.TypeOf(Mover).MethodByName("TurnRight") // would suffice, but
    // fails because you can't instantiate an interface
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Uaidml8KMV. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a `reflect.Type` for a type with this trick:

```
tp := reflect.TypeOf((*Mover)(nil)).Elem()
```

That is, create a typed nil pointer and then get the type of what it points at.

A simple way to determine if a `reflect.Type` implements a particular method signature is to use its `Implements` method with an appropriate interface type.  Something like this should do:

```
type TurnRighter interface {
    TurnRight() bool
}
TurnRighterType := reflect.TypeOf((*TurnRighter)(nil)).Elem()
fmt.Println(tp.Implements(TurnRighterType))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty crafty.